# How to change the checkpoint to the latest schema version in AWS Glue schema registry using AWS Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

In AWS Glue schema registry, the schema evolution compatibility checks are done only against the very first version(which has the checkpoint).
How to change the checkpoint to the latest schema version in AWS Glue schema registry using AWS Java SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `updateSchema` is the method of `com.amazonaws.services.glue`
you are looking for.

```
    updateSchema(UpdateSchemaRequest updateSchemaRequest)
Updates the description, compatibility setting, or version checkpoint for a schema set.
```

More info in [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/glue/AWSGlue.html#updateSchema-com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.UpdateSchemaRequest-).